# STM32G491 UART_RxEventCallBack doesn't work properly?

Tags: callback, stm32, uart, rs485

I'm trying to communicate 2 rs485  IC with 1 STM32. I'm using 2 different uart for 2 IC. Both of them receive with DMA or transmit but when I try using both together it only receive data? In another project I did it with 2uart and 1 STM. Here is my code

I want to receive data from uart2 and transmit from uart3;

```
void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Size)
{
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(UART3_EN_GPIO_Port, UART3_EN_Pin,1); //to transmit data 
   HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart3, tx3_buffer, sizeof(tx3_buffer));
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(UART3_EN_GPIO_Port, UART3_EN_Pin,0); //turn to receive mode
   HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart2, rx2_buffer, sizeof(tx2_buffer));
}

int main()
{
HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart2, rx2_buffer, sizeof(tx2_buffer));
HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart3, tx3_buffer, sizeof(tx3_buffer));

  while()
  {
  }
}
```

As I said I use this structure before, it worked but now it only receive data. When I only write HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA it transmit or only write HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA it receive.